# Visual studio 2019 Blazor Client Side option is not visible

Tags: visual-studio-2019, .net-core-3.0, blazor-client-side

I updated vs 2019 to 16.0.1 after .net core 3 is released. But I cannot find all the options for blazor. I can just see the blazor server side option, but nothing else. Funny enough the template are visible in command line.

```html
Blazor Server App ------ blazorserver    
                                                                  
Blazor (hosted in ASP.NET server) ----- blazorhosted

Blazor Library ----- blazorlib       

Blazor (Server-side in ASP.NET Core) ---- blazorserverside

Blazor (standalone) ----- blazor
```

But can't see the client-side option in visual studio. I had .net core 3-preview installed. Which I have uninstalled already just in case, but that didn't help. Anybody else faced this issue?

Comment: hi, try to flip between frameworks and it will be visible, this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63049646/893865

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue with dotnet core 3.1.100 and visual studio of version 16.0.1

I was able to get this template by upgrading my visual studio to version 16.7.2 which comes with dotnet core 3.1.401 and Blazor WebAssembly App.

Upgrade your visual studio 2019 using the installer.

Answer (score 0):

Must use Visual Studio Preview for now. If you add the project using command line or preview, you can open it in non-preview Visual Studio, however I wouldn't suggest it. Blazor client-side is in a state of flux, you are gonna want all the latest bits which will only be available in preview until official release. Use preview to add and edit Blazor wasm projects.

https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/preview/