# Blazor WebAssembly template not found in Blazor new project

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-client-side, asp.net-blazor

I have installed dotnet [SDK 3.1.201](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1) to Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019 Version **16.5.4** and I installed this template   `dotnet new -i Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Templates::3.2.0-preview5.20216.8` after that I statred to create a new Blazor project in VS just only contains the Blazor Server App template I didn't find the Blazor WebAssembly App template what is wrong with all steps that I have done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem when I tried to install the template, my problem was I made a simple Nuget package for myself but it was deleted in Nuget Package Manager if you have any package that not available please delete it. 
I have this error during install the Blazor template ( error : The local source 'C:\Users\mypc\Desktop\dotnet-standard-getting-started\demos\Testingapp.Storage\bin\Debug' doesn't exist. )
Tools ---> Options ---> under Nuget Package Manager[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need the preview version of Visual Studio (16.6)

> If you’re on Windows using Visual Studio, we recommend installing the
>   latest preview of Visual Studio 2019 16.6. For this preview, you
>   should still install the template from the command-line as described
>   above to ensure that the Blazor WebAssembly template shows up
>   correctly in Visual Studio and on the command-line.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/blazor-webassembly-3-2-0-preview-5-release-now-available/

Comment: Hey @Inktkiller I can install another template ? and not use the latest version of VS what is your recommendation if I not install VS 16.6 is there anyway to use Blazor WebAssembly template ? thanks

Comment: @MR_WELL you could try the CLI commands like `dotnet new blazorwasm -o WebApplication1` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/get-started?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=netcore-cli

Answer (score 0):

Before you select Blazor project type (Server or Web-Assembly step) **just flip between frameworks** (3.0 and 3.1), the menu will be updated and you will be able to see WASM Blazor version:

[image]